# How to add Message Box with ScrollBar on the Button Click in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Hi I am new to Windows Phone 7.1 development .. How can I add Message Box inside Grid with ScrollBar as my Message is big on the Button Click Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ChildWindow control as detailed in the following blog post :-

http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/17/Using_ChildWindow_in_Windows_Phone_7_Projects